# Surface in a product domain

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds

Let $M$ be a connected closed surface. Suppose $N$ is a connected closed surface embedded in the interior of $M \times [0,1]$ such that $N$ separates $M \times \{0\}$ and $M \times \{1\}$. Can we prove the region bounded by $M \times \{0\}$ and $N$ is homeomorphic to $M \times [0,1]$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true in general.

One way to build examples is via "stabilisation".  Take $N_0 = M \times \{1/2\}$. Suppose that $\alpha$ is an arc in $M \times [0,1]$ with the following properties.

- $\alpha$ is simple (does not self-intersect).
- $\alpha \cap N_0 = \partial \alpha$.
- $\alpha$ is isotopic, relative to its boundary, to a simple arc embedded in $N_0$.

We take a regular neighbourhood of $N_0 \cup \alpha$.  Let $N$ be the boundary component of the neighbourhood that is on the same side of $N_0$ as $\alpha$ is.  The genus of $N$ is one higher than that of $M$.  Also, $N$ separates $M \times \{0\}$ from $M \times \{1\}$.

Of course the arc $\alpha$ could also be "knotted".  Also, we could stabilise more than once.  Finally, we could combine these operations in various ways. It is a pretty theorem, appearing early in the theory of three-manifolds that fibre over the circle, that the above operations are all that can happen.

Comment: Is the original conclusion true if we assume $N$ is homeomorphic to $M$?

Comment: Yes.  If $N$ separates the boundary components, and is homeomorphic to $M$, then there is an ambient isotopy taking $N$ to $M$.

Comment: Could you give a reference for this fact?

Comment: I poked around, and could not find an obvious place to point to on-line.  I'll guess that this appears in either Jaco's book or Hempel's - unfortunately I don't have them to hand.  The proof is not so difficult, however.  Suppose that $M$ has genus $g$.  Fix a cell structure on $M$ with one vertex, $2g$ edges, and one $4g$-gon (as the two-cell).  Cross this with the closed interval to get a cell structure on $M \times [0, 1]$.  Isotope $N$ to be in general position with respect to the one- and two-cells of the cell structure on $M \times [0, 1]$.  Since $N$ separates the boundary components,

Comment: it meets the internal one-cell an odd number of times.  We now perform isotopies of $N$ to ensure that all intersections of $N$ with the "vertical" rectangles (two-cells in the interior of $M \times [0, 1]$) are horizontal arcs.  Also, we can arrange that intersections of $N$ with the three-cell are disks.  We deduce that $N$ meets the internal one-cell exactly once.  A final isotopy gives the result. 

Here is a more algebraic proof: compress $N$ to be incompressible, appeal to Dehn's lemma to deduce that $N$ is essential, and then use the classification of subgroups of surface groups.

Comment: By the way, if I’ve answered your original question, it is polite (and tidy) to accept the answer. :)